# Custom activity indicator stops suddenly

Tags: ios, animation

I've created custom activity indicator:I have an image and rotate it. But sometimes its animation suddenly stops.
I've tried some ways to create animation:
[UIView animateWithDuration:] with repeat animation in completionBlock, 
timer that increase the transform angle and repeats.

And both still don't work. If there're lots of db operations animation stops.

What else can I do?

Comment: Make sure you don't do UI blocking operations. Those db operations that you are talking, are performed on main thread ?

Comment: Almost all of them are in background threads, but my UI is blocked. What are other UI blocking operations?

Comment: In order to find the blocking operations, when the UI freezes just pause the app execution, then go to the "Debug Navigator" and then check what is running on Thread 1 (queue:com.apple.main-thread)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    activityView.center=self.view.center;

    [activityView startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:activityView];

- (void)startupAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
}


http://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/ios-dev-custom-activityindicatorview/
```

Comment: Thanks. But I really need custom indicator.

Comment: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html   may be this tutorial is help full

Comment: They're using activity indicator. But I need rotating image)

Comment: http://www.techjini.com/blog/different-type-custom-activity-indicator-spinner/  https://github.com/TechJini/iOS-Custom-Activity-Indicator    http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html